# How to fix data not showing with sql query/java?

Tags: java

Good day all. I am coming to a problem where I implement `xPayService.getJobAutocomplete("searchValue");` and my data has been stopped showing in my frontend. can anyone check what is going on to help me fix it. thanks

Here is my java code:

```
          // this is in different class 
 public void loadSearchList() throws SQLException, NamingException, URISyntaxException, IOException, ParseException {
     List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList = xPayService.getJobAutocomplete("searchValue");
        this.setJobSearchItems(jobSearchList);
    }

// this is into another class too.
public List<JobSearchItem> getJobAutocomplete(String searchValue)  {
        String sValue = "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%";
        return dataUtilityService.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_GET_AUTOCOMPLETE, 
                        new Object[]{sValue, sValue}, jobSearchItemMapper);
    }
```

Comment: getJobAutocomplete takes a string argument but you are calling it with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that question is updated later so this is partial answer now**

`getJobAutocomplete` expects a parameter and you are not passing it that is the reason you are getting an error.

Replace your string search value with `your_serach_string` in the line below and it should work

```
List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList =xPayService.getJobAutocomplete("search_string");
```

**Update**

In below code you should pass your query string. for ex if you want to search for an apple then you should pass apple in the code below.

```
String search = "apple"
List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList = xPayService.getJobAutocomplete(search);
    this.setJobSearchItems(jobSearchList);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188124/discussion-between-jainik-and-mike).